# FAPI #prefix YAML filter tag

Tags: forms, 8

```
  button_submit:
   '#prefix': '<div class="col-md-4 text-right">text<button>button text</button>'
   '#suffix': '</div>'
   '#value': Send
   '#type': submit
```

I have the code above in YAML form. When I edit the code, I see the button tag; when rendering, only the following markup is left.

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-right">
ALGOasd
<input id="edit-button-submit" class="button js-form-submit form-submit" type="submit" value="Send" name="op" data-drupal-selector="edit-button-submit">
</div>
```

It´s clear that I have some filter, but I can't find it out. I also tried putting a `<button>` in a container item, but the same thing happens.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the #allowed_tags property which is applied to #markup, #prefix, and #suffix. (See: [Pass raw html to #markup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184963/pass-raw-html-to-markup))

```
button_submit:
  '#prefix': '<div class="col-md-4 text-right">text<button>button text</button>'
  '#suffix': '</div>'
  '#value': Send
  '#type': submit
  '#allowed_tags':
    - div
    - button
```