# Add inline JavaScript to end of page dynamically

Tags: 8, javascript

Use case:

I have a custom block:

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Hello' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "my",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("My Block"),
 * )
 */
class MyBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $build = array(
      '#markup' => 'SOME WEIRD ADS HTML HERE'
    );

    SOME_COOL_STUFF_TO_ADD_INLINE_JAVASCRIPT_TO_THE_CLOSING_BODY_TAG

    return $build;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to add inline javascript to the end of the page just when this block is rendered anywhere (in theme or panel page)?

Comment: The answer is actually no, not really. You can ad it right there  as inline within the #markup (you might need to create a safe string with Markup::create). But what you can do for example is combine a library with drupalSettings to instrumentalize it. And then loop over ad positions in a drupal behavior based on the settings. That's what we're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You just use the following code.

```
$build = [
  '#markup' => 'SOME WEIRD ADS HTML HERE',
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => ['mymodule/mylibrary'],
  ],
];
```

Follow [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets) to learn how to define a library for Drupal 8, and keep in mind that, by default, JavaScript files are added to the footer, as explained in [`LibraryDiscoveryParser::parseLibraryInfo()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Asset%21LibraryDiscoveryParser.php/function/LibraryDiscoveryParser%3A%3AparseLibraryInfo/8.2.x).

> By default, JavaScript files are included in the footer.

Also, `#markup` is filtered out, as explained in [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x).

> **#markup**: Specifies that the array provides HTML markup directly. Unless the markup is very simple, such as an explanation in a paragraph tag, it is normally preferable to use #theme or #type instead, so that the theme can customize the markup. Note that the value is passed through [`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/function/Xss%3A%3AfilterAdmin/8.2.x), which **strips known XSS vectors while allowing a permissive list of HTML tags that are not XSS vectors**. (For example, `<script>` and `<style>` are not allowed.) See [`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::$adminTags`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/property/Xss%3A%3AadminTags/8.2.x) for the list of tags that will be allowed. If your markup needs any of the tags that are not in this whitelist, then you can implement a theme hook and template file and/or an asset library. Alternatively, you can use the render array key #allowed_tags to alter which tags are filtered.