# Why is a ISO:8601 date within a time tag converted to zeroes?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I've been attaching [Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com) script to my themes and it requires dates to be formatted like this.

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</time>
```

In a view, I have one field set to rewrite as follows.

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="{{ Created_1 }}">{{ Created }}</time>
```

The previous version of the script made use of the Unix Epoch time format (U), but the most recent one available shifted to ISO:8601 (c). I found out today after updating the script that the view is converting the ISO dates within every time tag into double zeros (00).

The resulting html will be like this in both of the admin and site themes:

```
 <time class="timeago" datetime="00">
```

For some reason I can get the ISO date to print outside of the time tag but not within the datetime portion of the time tag.

How do I stop it from doing that?

My reasoning for using time ago is that it is more linguistically accurate than the format supplied by Drupal. For example, check the difference in formats between [Arabic](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/locales/jquery.timeago.ar.js) and [English](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/locales/jquery.timeago.en.js). Is something like this achievable solely through the translation interface? It would be nice to know if it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "double zeros"? Does this mean that the only text within the field is `00`? Or that the time is zero-prefixed? Or that the microsends are all zeros? You should be as specific as possible about the output that you actually see.

Comment: The resulting html will be like this: <time class="timeago" datetime="00"> in both of the admin and site themes. For some reason I can get the ISO date to print outside of the time tag but not within the datetime portion of the time tag.

Comment: I think your datetime attribute value might got filtered, for example, by xss:filter or something like that during the rendering process, because of the punctuation (dash and colon). Especially you mentioned that it was working fine when it's a simple timestamp value. One workaround would be trying to see if you are able to do this in the views without rewriting this field.

Comment: That might be it. I did some googling earlier and found this topic: 
Xss::filterAdmin() incorrectly filters time elements
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2692451

What other ways are there to output a datetime field as a time tag? Do I have to come up with my own field plugin or twig filter?

Comment: @Jed_BH If your theme has good html5 support then it's just a matter of adding a class to it via views UI. If not you can still create a simple date field formatter.

Comment: Wouldn't that class just get filtered all the same? I had a stab at the field formatter, not sure if it'' work but found out that datetime formatters don't affect authored fields..

Comment: In your formatter, instead of returning a '#markup', you can return a 'inline_template', this will keep it from getting filtered. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184963/pass-raw-html-to-markup for an example.