# Add inline style to render array attributes, without XSS filtering

Tags: 8, theming

I wish to use an inline style to add a dynamically generated background image URL to a div, e.g.

```
  $build[0] = [
    '#type'       => 'container',
    '#attributes' => [
      'id' => 'thumbnail-image',
      // the example below is a YouTube thumbnail, to be cropped using other CSS
      'style' => sprintf('background-image: url("https://img.youtube.com/vi/1234567890/sddefault.jpg");', $video),
    ]
  ];
  return $build;
```

The XSS filtering silently drops `style` attributes.  Can I disable that for an individual render array, or otherwise work around it?

Note: this is generating output for a Field Formatter, used in a view.

The [official advice](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x) is:

> If your markup needs any of the tags not in this whitelist, then you
>   can implement a theme hook and/or an asset library. Alternatively, you
>   can use the key #allowed_tags to alter which tags are filtered.

#### Things tried:

1) **using a theme hook and a template**

Here's my template:

```
<div class="test" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ video_id }}/sddefault.jpg');">Sample output</div>
```

It's working, except the style attribute is still being stripped out.

2) **#allowed_tags** (but it's not a tag, it's an attribute):

```
'#allowed_tags' => array_merge(\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::getAdminTagList(), ['style']),
```

**Successful workaround**:

This code is in a field formatter for views, so I overrode the default views template. The views templates allowed a `style` attribute to pass through as I would have expected.

Initially I made a template for one specific field, but the problem was I needed to access the values of a separate field too and it was proving hard/impossible to retrieve them with the `row._entity` variable.

So then I decided to use `views-view-fields.html.twig` instead, which gives access to all the fields. This took rather longer, but as my code had a couple of conditionals and some variables used more than once, on balance the end result is cleaner than doing everything in the UI. (It's worth leaving yourself a note in the view UI admin comment and any docs that the view field is overwritten.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `'#type' => 'inline_template'` for this: You can do everything what you can do in a regular `.twig` file, just inlined in code:

```
  $build[0] = [
    '#type'       => 'inline_template',
    '#template'   => '<div id="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url({{ foo }})">{{ bar }}</div>'
    '#context' => [
      'foo' => $youtube_thumbnail
      'bar' => $whatever
    ]
  ];
  return $build;
```

Here is a [complete list of render elements / `#type`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21ElementInterface.php/interface/implements/ElementInterface/8.8.x) 's for render arrays. (For Forms API, here is the [sub-list of FormRenderElements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElementInterface.php/interface/implements/FormElementInterface/8.8.x))

Comment: Yep, I understand why an inline template is easier, but the problem is *however* I write the tag (render array, external twig file, inline_template, even using \Core\Render\Markup) the `style` attribute is being removed by the XSS Filter.

Comment: `#type => markup` is going through XSS filter, however the source of a Twig templates should not. (Can't test right now, but neither inline styles nor JS are usually filtered when written directly into Twig)

Comment: My hunch is because it's a Field Formatter, maybe Views does something? (Think I might open an issue about it on drupal.org)