# How to embed HTML and CSS in a custom form element?

Tags: theming, forms

This worked in Drupal 7 but isn't in Drupal 8.

```
$form['covid-19'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div style="border: 2px solid red;padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;"><strong>Due to the COVID-19 situation, we will only be purchasing e-books and e-audiobooks at this time.</strong> You are welcome to enter your information for print books, DVDs, or CDs, and they will be purchased when the libraries re-open.  Inter-library Loans [loans from outside Yavapai County] are suspended for now.</div>',
);
```

I want the div with style info to stay intact so I can just comment it out when the crisis is over. Then I want to leave it there as a placeholder ready for the next crisis.

In this example, the strong tag makes it through but the div does not.

I also tried setting the div info as a #prefix and #suffix but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: See [Pass raw html to #markup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/184963/89581) for numerous workarounds to the (intentional) filtering of markup on rendering.  Personally, I think it would probably be easier to just add a `.crisis` class to your site css...

Comment: Thanks for that link. Here's what worked for me: use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

[..]
return [
  '#markup' => Markup::create($html),
];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup strips away some tags and attributes. Here is a way to do it.

Add a class to your form

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'crisis';
```

Add css rule to your theme's css

```
.crisis {
    display: none;
}
```

if you do not have a library and a .css file to use, you need to create them. Define a library in your theme or module in your `THEMEorMODULE.libraries.yml`

```
crisis:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/crisis.css: {}
```

create `css/crisis.css` file and put your css rule(s) in it

and attach the library to your form

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEMEorMODULE/crisis'
```

and clear cache

NOTE: The above (pseudo)code is not tested.  For more information please have a look [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)

Comment: This is valuable information and I'm sure I'm going to use it soon. But for this situation I really wanted to keep everything in one place.