# Adding an icon in a form item element

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form where we are displaying a static text like:

```
Please select the <icon> button to view X
```

Where the icon is a an image. I've added this piece to the form by doing the following:

```
$form['message'] = [
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => $message
];
```

However, when `$message` contains the icon like `Please select the <img src=....> button to view X`, the image tag appears instead of the image. I can't do separate items because the text is translated, so how can I insert an image in the middle of a sentence like this?

The code that sets `$message` I tried is the following.

```php
$message = 'Please select the <img src="icon.jpg" alt="my icon"> button to view this page';
```

```php
$message = '<div>Please select the <img src="icon.jpg" alt="my icon"> button to view this page</div>';
```

```php
$message = '<p>Please select the <img src="icon.jpg" alt="my icon"> button to view this page</p>';
```

I also tried setting the allowed tags with `#allowed_tags` as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass raw html to #markup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184963/pass-raw-html-to-markup)

Comment: This is because the value provided in `#markup` is checked for XSS and filtered out any non-required markups.. There are many other ways like use `#inline_template` or use `#allowed_tags` in #markup, etc..  to achieve this functionality. 
Please read the answers here to know why your markup is not correctly rendering. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184963/pass-raw-html-to-markup

Comment: @JayKandari unfortunately I tired both the `#allowed_tags` approach and the `#inline_template` and neither worked. Is `img` not an `allowed tag`? I even tried converting my translatable markup (the message) to a raw string and I am seeing the same results. Does `Markup` not do `img` tags or something?